# Why it does not show the actual length of buttons after window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', myfunction(){...})?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic

Here is my code:

```js
const btnList = [{
    id: 'all',
    content: 'All'
  },
  {
    id: 'br',
    content: 'Breakfast'
  },
  {
    id: 'dn',
    content: 'Dinner'
  }
]

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const btnz = document.getElementById('btnz');
  let newBtn = '';
  btnList.forEach(btn => {
    newBtn += `<button id="${btn.id}" class="btn-item">${btn.content}</button>`
  })
  btnz.innerHTML = newBtn;

})

const btnCollection = btnz.querySelectorAll('.btn-item');
console.log(btnCollection);
btnCollection.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item')
    if (e.currentTarget.id === 'all') {
      items.forEach(i => {
        i.classList.add('show')
      })
    } else if (e.currentTarget.id === 'br') {
      items.forEach(x => {
        if (x.dataset.id === 'br') {
          x.classList.add('show')
        } else {
          x.classList.remove('show')
        }
      })
    } else if (e.currentTarget.id === 'dn') {
      items.forEach(x => {
        if (x.dataset.id === 'dn') {
          x.classList.add('show')
        } else {
          x.classList.remove('show')
        }
      })
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.item {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wr">
    <h1>Menu</h1>
    <div id="btnz"></div>
    <div class="disp">
      <div class="item item1" data-id='br'>item1</div>
      <div class="item item2" data-id='dn'>item2</div>
      <div class="item item3" data-id='br'>item3</div>
      <div class="item item4" data-id='dn'>item4</div>
      <div class="item item5" data-id='br'>item5</div>
      <div class="item item6" data-id='dn'>item6</div>
      <div class="item item7" data-id='br'>item7</div>
      <div class="item item8" data-id='dn'>item8</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I do not understand why my code is not working properly after adding dynamic buttons, please help. Why console.log(btnCollection) outside of window.addEventListener() shows nothing?

Is there any better (best practise) way to handle filtering with dynamic buttons?
I am an amateur, so do not hestitate to ask any related question and explaining in detail what is going on here. Thanks before.

Comment: The code outside the `DOMContentLoaded` listener function is running before that function runs, so the buttons haven't been added yet.

Comment: Put all the rest of the JS code inside the callback function.

Comment: The entire point of `addEventListener` is to supply a function that will not immediately but at some point in the future.

Comment: @Barmar and Chris Thank you too much guys. It took me couple days to think about it. So, what are you doing in such cases in professional way? Are you putting every dynamic stuff inside window.addEvent.. or are you creating separate functions?

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const btnz = document.getElementById('btnz');
  let newBtn = '';
  btnList.forEach(btn => {
    newBtn += `<button id="${btn.id}" class="btn-item">${btn.content}</button>`
  })
  btnz.innerHTML = newBtn;

  //you are calling console before this event listener been executed;
  //put it (and every method that dependes of it) inside the event listener callback
    
  const btnCollection = btnz.querySelectorAll('.btn-item');
  console.log(btnCollection);

})
```